# Matlab - output of the algorithm

Tags: matlab

I have a program using `PSO algorithm` using `penalty` function for `Constraint Satisfaction`. But when I run the program for different iterations, the output of the algorithm would be :

> "Iteration 1: Best Cost = Inf"

.

Does anyone know why I always get `inf` answer?

Comment: @Himanshu Please use code markup only for code, not to highlight random words. Proper names are written with initial capital letters, not with code markup.

Comment: Made little formatting for better readability and edited heading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be many reasons for that, none of which will be accurate if you don't provide a MWE with the code you have already tried or a context of the function you are analysing.

For instance, while studying the PSO algorithm you might use it on [functions which have analytical solutions first](http://www.sfu.ca/~ssurjano/optimization.html). By doing this you can study the behaviour of the algorithm before applying to a similar problem, and fine tune its parameters.

My guess is that you might not be providing either the right function (I have done that already, getting a signal wrong is easy!), the right constraints (same logic applies), your weights for the penalty function and velocity update are way off.

Comment: You're right. I checked it out and got it that I didn't define the Cost Function properly. Thanks at all.

Comment: Hey brodroll, sorry. My problem has not been completely solved. I changed my Cost function and now the cost of particles is calculated for some of them but not for all. Each time I run the program, the cost of some particles would be inf and next time is changed. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @Lilly Are you sure you are initializing all your particles within the domain and that after the penalty parameters are appropriate for the problem? Again I can't really help you without any code.....